# utilizar funcion SUM dos veces al mismo tiempo sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

trabajo sql management estudio 2018
Buen día tengo un problema, a ver si me pueden ayudar 
ando sumando cantidades   de los id's que son iguales  utilizo la funcion sum y no tengo ningun problema (Sacos los subtotales). Ahora lo que necesito que los resultados que me salieron  los vuelva a sumar y  saque el total  final. pero no se como hacer ya que utilice  el sum alguna idea estes mi codigo

```
    `SELECT fac.ID_Solicitud ,
     sum (fac.importePendientePago) as pago , 
     div.descripcion
     FROM LIT_Factura fac
     inner join LIT_SRCartera RC on RC.Id_solicitud=fac.ID_Solicitud
     inner join CAT_Subsidiaria sub on sub.ID_Subsidiaria=RC.ID_Sociedad
     inner  join CAT_Division div on div.ID_Division=sub.ID_Division
     where div.ID_Division=2
     group by fac.ID_Solicitud,  div.descripcion`
```

[image: mi resultado de mi quuery, quiero que pago lo vuelva a sumar y saque el total final]

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Podes poner un ejemplo mas claro? creo que alcanza con que agrupes de otra forma, pero no me queda claro

Comment: por ejemplo  en la imagen muestra    un id "3"  todas las solicitudes con id=3  se suman  con lq funcion SUM, y es el campo pago, ya utilize la funcion sum para todos los id que se repitan, ahora quiero hacer la    suma total  de pago   de todos ejmplo 5434+76566, tomando en cuenta que ya tengo un  SUM para los ids repetidos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es "agregar" un total a la consulta que ya tienes, la anterior respuesta solo te sirve si la incorporas en un `union` con la consulta original, y además como ya señaló gbianchi, es totalmente innecesario el `group by` y la subconsulta, si buscas el total simplemente quita el `group by` y las columnas por las que agrupas. Sin embargo, usando [`common table expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) se simplifica bastante la consulta. En este caso usamos la misma consulta dos veces, una para el detalle y otra para el total general:

```
;
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT fac.ID_Solicitud ,
         div.descripcion,
         sum (fac.importePendientePago) as pago
         FROM LIT_Factura fac
         inner join LIT_SRCartera RC on RC.Id_solicitud=fac.ID_Solicitud
         inner join CAT_Subsidiaria sub on sub.ID_Subsidiaria=RC.ID_Sociedad
         inner  join CAT_Division div on div.ID_Division=sub.ID_Division
         where div.ID_Division=2
         group by fac.ID_Solicitud,  div.descripcion
)
SELECT ID_Solicitud, descripcion, pago
       FROM CTE
UNION 
SELECT NULL, 'Total', SUM(pago)
       FROM CTE
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select sum(pago) as pago from
(SELECT fac.ID_Solicitud ,
     sum (fac.importePendientePago) as pago , 
     div.descripcion
     FROM LIT_Factura fac
     inner join LIT_SRCartera RC on RC.Id_solicitud=fac.ID_Solicitud
     inner join CAT_Subsidiaria sub on sub.ID_Subsidiaria=RC.ID_Sociedad
     inner  join CAT_Division div on div.ID_Division=sub.ID_Division
     where div.ID_Division=2
     group by fac.ID_Solicitud,  div.descripcion) a
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: No entiendo para que hacer todo esto, si alcanza con hacer un sum sin el group by y solo con el where.... :/